# Query re-write in materialized view with the defining query having 'union all' in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I'm trying some workouts on materialized views(mViews) , so that whether mViews can be used to gain the performance of query execution.

As a part of this activity, have created the following mView

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v2mv_fast_accunion12
 BUILD IMMEDIATE
 refresh fast  start WITH sysdate next (sysdate + 1)
 ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
   SELECT 1 AS marker,d.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,d.FFPPROGRAM,d.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS,
   NULL  AS tot_records,b.RECEIVERALERTCODE receiver_alert,b.SENDERALERT sender_alert,
   a.ROWID ra,b.ROWID rb,c.ROWID rc,d.ROWID rd
 FROM PAI_FILE A ,  PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL B,pai_file c,pai_valid_accrual d
 WHERE a.file_id= b.file_id AND
 c.file_id = d.file_id
 AND a.filetype=1
 AND c.filetype=2
 AND b.transactionid=d.transactionid

 UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS marker,b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,b.FFPPROGRAM,b.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS,b.file_id AS tot_records,
b.RECEIVERALERTCODE receiver_alert,b.SENDERALERT sender_alert,a.ROWID ra,b.ROWID rb,NULL AS rc,NULL AS rd
FROM   pai_file a,pai_valid_accrual b
WHERE a.file_id=b.file_id
AND
a.filetype=1
 ;
```

The materialized view got created. The capabilities of the created mView is as follows

```
MV_REPORT

Capable of: 

  REFRESH_COMPLETE

  REFRESH_FAST

  REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT

  REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML

  REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML
```

then i'm trying to make the query re-write working for the below query

```
SELECT  OPERATINGAIRLINECODE OPE,FFPPROGRAM FFP,
COUNT(TOTALNUMBEROFRECORDS) TOTALNUMBEROFRECORDS,
SUM(ACCRUAL_01) ACCRUAL_01,SUM(ACCRUAL_03) ACCRUAL_03,
COUNT( REJECT_HUB) REJECT_HUB,SUM(ACCRUAL_02) ACCRUAL_02,
SUM(Alertedbyhub) Alertedbyhub
FROM ( 
   SELECT d.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,d.FFPPROGRAM, NULL  AS TOTALNUMBEROFRECORDS ,
CASE WHEN d.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS = '01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACCRUAL_01,
CASE WHEN d.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS = '03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACCRUAL_03,
NULL AS REJECT_HUB,
CASE WHEN d.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS = '02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACCRUAL_02,
 NULL AS  Alertedbyhub  
 FROM PAI_FILE A ,  PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL B,pai_file c,pai_valid_accrual d
 WHERE a.file_id= b.file_id AND
 c.file_id = d.file_id
 AND a.filetype=1
 AND c.filetype=2
 AND a.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN To_Date('20150101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AND To_Date('20150130 23:59:59','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
 AND b.transactionid=d.transactionid
 AND d.accrualpostingstatus IN ('01','02','03')
 AND d.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE IN ('AB')

 UNION ALL 


SELECT b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,b.FFPPROGRAM,b.file_id TOTALNUMBEROFRECORDS,
NULL AS ACCRUAL_01,NULL AS ACCRUAL_03,NULL AS REJECT_HUB,NULL AS ACCRUAL_02,
CASE WHEN b.RECEIVERALERTCODE IS NOT NULL OR b.SENDERALERT         IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Alertedbyhub
FROM   pai_file a,pai_valid_accrual b
WHERE a.file_id=b.file_id
AND
a.filetype=1
AND a.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN To_Date('20150101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AND To_Date('20150130 23:59:59','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
AND b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE IN ('AB')

UNION ALL 

SELECT B.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,B.FFPPROGRAM,NULL AS TOTALNUMBEROFRECORDS,NULL AS ACCRUAL_01,
NULL AS ACCRUAL_03,b.rejected_accrual_id REJECT_HUB,NULL AS ACCRUAL_02,
NULL AS Alertedbyhub
FROM  pai_file a,pai_rejected_accrual b
WHERE a.file_id = b.file_id
AND A.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN To_Date('20150101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AND To_Date('20150130 23:59:59','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
AND b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE IN ('AB')

) WHERE (OPERATINGAIRLINECODE IS NOT NULL AND  FFPPROGRAM IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,FFPPROGRAM;
```

In the above query, i'm expecting the first and second union query subsets to make use of the mView created.

Checked the explain plan for the query. but it's not using the mView via query rewrite.

here's the explain plan for the query

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                      |  1146 | 50424 |       |  1116K  (1)| 03:43:13 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY            |                      |  1146 | 50424 |       |  1116K  (1)| 03:43:13 |
|   2 |   VIEW                    |                      |  6958K|   291M|       |  1115K  (1)| 03:43:10 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL              |                      |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN             |                      |  2453K|   198M|  2432K|   646K  (1)| 02:09:23 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PAI_FILE             | 88658 |  1385K|       |  1102   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|*  6 |      HASH JOIN            |                      |  3945K|   259M|   116M|   630K  (1)| 02:06:07 |
|*  7 |       HASH JOIN           |                      |  2220K|    91M|       |   458K  (1)| 01:31:46 |
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PAI_FILE             | 86013 |   671K|       |  1099   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|*  9 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL    |  3680K|   122M|       |   457K  (1)| 01:31:32 |
|  10 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| ACCRUAL_IDX7         |    52M|  1295M|       | 71813   (1)| 00:14:22 |
|* 11 |     HASH JOIN             |                      |  4500K|   133M|  2432K|   467K  (1)| 01:33:30 |
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PAI_FILE             | 88658 |  1385K|       |  1102   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|* 13 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL    |  7237K|   103M|       |   456K  (1)| 01:31:24 |
|* 14 |     HASH JOIN             |                      |  4672 |   132K|       |  1546   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|* 15 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PAI_REJECTED_ACCRUAL |  4672 | 74752 |       |   442   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|* 16 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PAI_FILE             |   359K|  4561K|       |  1102   (1)| 00:00:14 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am i missing anything for making the query rewrite to work using 'union all' ?

whether the approach to use mView this way is a correct one? suggest me please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can check why it is not being used, there are a few things that influence this.

But the DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_REWRITE procedure advises whether query rewrite is possible on a query and, if so, which materialized views will be used. It also explains why a query cannot be rewritten.

More info on how to use this you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#i997015)